# C# foreach count doesn't count correctly with Amrykid.Web.IRC API

Tags: c#, web, foreach, irc

I have a problem with counting the total users in my irc channel.
If my IRC bot joins after all the users, it counts them all. If someone leave, it counts correctly. But, when someone join, it doesn't add a user to the count somehow.

What could be wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
if (message.Replace("!", "").StartsWith("users"))
{
    try
    {
        int count = ch.UserCount = 0;

        foreach (string u in ch.Users)
        {
            count += 1;
        }

        _irc.SendMessage("Users Online: " + count, IRC.SupportedColors.Red, ch.Channel);
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        _irc.SendMessage("Error: " + ee.Message, IRC.SupportedColors.Red, ch.Channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you definably call the function when one is added? If yes do you call it before 'ch' has updated fully?

Comment: If a user joins the chat, simply increment the count instead of counting all of them again.Same about leaving

Comment: I am assuming `Users` is some sort of `IEnumerable`. Why aren't using the `Count` extention method?

Comment: well, what exactly is `ch.Users`? `foreach` will be working just fine here; the suspects a: `ch.Users` poorly implemented, b: the user wasn't actually added, c: threading

Comment: @MarcGravell ch.Users is from the API with the code line: 
public static void _irc_IRCMessageRecieved(object sender, string message, User user, IRCChannel ch)

Comment: @ErikHampus and again; what is `ch.Users`? Is this "Amry.Web.IRC" a well-known thing? I don't seem to be able to find it on google... in fact: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ouhOb.png

Comment: @MarcGravell I found the API here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/152909-amrykidwebirc/ . I can't find the specific download link I used, but it had like 70k downloads. ch.Users stands for 'IRCChannel.Users', so it defines all the users in the specific joined channel(s).

Comment: Since `ch.UserCount` is a writeable property, what is it for? What effect does setting it to 0 have?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [`Amrykid.Web.IRC`](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/152909-amrykidwebirc/), `ch.Users` (where `ch` is an `IRCChannel`) is a `string[]`:

```
public string[] Users {
    get {
        return this._users;
    }
}
```

`foreach` is perfectly capable of looping over an array correctly, although if all you want to do is *count* the users, `.Length` would be more efficient.

Whatever the problem is: it has nothing to do with `foreach`, and everything to do with one of:

- the library being buggy
- incorrect expectations about the library
- incorrect usage of the library

It seems, however, a support question for `Amrykid.Web.IRC`.

Glancing at `AddUser`, it seems that it only adds *unique* users:

```
internal void AddUser(string user)
{
    Collection<string> source = new Collection<string>();
    try
    {
        foreach (string str in this._users)
        {
            source.Add(str);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    if (!source.Contains(user))
    {
        source.Add(user);
    }
    this._users = null;
    this._users = source.ToArray<string>();
}
```

While this implementation isn't *particularly good*, it would appear to be functional.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I count the users with     .Length?

Comment: @ErikHampus `ch.Users` is an array; `ch.Users.Length` is the *length* of the array, aka: the number of users; so `int userCount = ch.Users.Length;`

Comment: It gives the same result as my first code. [6 users in channel] *bot joins and say 6 users* [1 user leaves] *bot says 5 users* [1 user rejoins] *bot still says 5 users*

Comment: I could send a raw message to the IRC server: '/raw NAMES #channel' but I don't know how to get the response.

Comment: @ErikHampus take that up with the library author... basically, the *library isn't reflecting user changes the way you want it to*. The *how to count items in an array*: is above. If the array *has the wrong contents*: not my fault

Answer (score 1):

When I created this library, I was a novice programmer so I would expect that this library would be buggy. While it's been a while since I've viewed the code, I do recommend that you use a better written library such as https://github.com/meebey/SmartIrc4net.